# Where does the term "Blutz Waves" first come from?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-manga

Trying to determine if this originated with GT, in a manga, an interview or I just missed hearing it in DBZ. As far as I'm aware the only discussion in DBZ and earlier referred to them simply as moon light.

Comment: Could you state where did you hear/see this from?

Comment: @AkiTanaka sorry, what do you mean "this" ? If "this" means blutz waves I know for sure existed in GT but I wonder if they actually exist in the main series or if it's just plain moon light. http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Blutz_Waves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a bit of backstory. **Blutz Waves** are defined as the following

> [An energy source emitted by large celestial bodies such as a full-moon or the Earth when it reflects rays of sunlight. They are alternatively called Bruits Rays, Fruits Rays, or Green-spectrum Radiations (in the English manga). When a Saiyan absorbs at least 17,000,000 zenos (ゼノ Zeno, unit used to measure waves of full celestial light) through the retina,[1] a reaction occurs in the tail that causes the Saiyans to transform into ruthless Great Apes. If a moon is not present, the Saiyan, if he/she knows how to use it, can also create an artificial moon to allow themselves to absorb the necessary amount of Blutz Waves needed for them to go Great Ape to compensate.](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Blutz_Waves)

Note that this concept of B.Waves existed in the manga, of DBZ in the saiyan arc. It was explored a bit heavier in GT and the term **Blutz Wave** was only used in GT but the concept was introduced as early as Dragon Ball but unexplored.

In Dragon Ball Z Gohan and Goku both had adverse reactions to seeing the attack ball(*the ship Goku came to earth on*) in the first arc against Raditz. Goku mentioned it felt familiar and Gohan flat out cried on site.

The attack balls used a similar form of the technology to produce artifical moons to trigger the reaction in combat. This is elaborated on further here:

> [Spaceships used by those under King Cold, Cooler and Frieza for interstellar travel. When the Saiyans were a part of the military, these vehicles also sent low-class Saiyans to distant locations, so that they would one day conquer and destroy worlds throughout the galaxy.](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Attack_Ball)

In short the moon simulator was kind of a last ditch defense given that the saiyans they send around flying at Faster than light speed for between 1-3 years are kept in suspended animation. If they were to be attacked immediately after exiting their ship they may have a hard time defending themselves.

The saiyans were also known for sending infants to conquer planets,the moon simulator for the transformation helps to aid that.

**In summation**

The concept has been around since the original DB and is cannon the concept being that **moon light from a full moon makes saiyans transform**, the term **blutz wave** came out of GT and is not cannon but it extends the concept with a term and definition. The story of why the ships had simulation engines to product moonlight/blutz waves is cannon and given that it comes with different details from Vegeta and Bardock. Bardock being a movie character but confirmed as cannon.

Though with super out and more saiyans on the scene. There might be a new term and explanation that comes out making Blutz waves a full on full non-cannon detail.

Comment: thx, your summation would've answered my q but the details made it ambiguous again. in the wiki it says "According to the anime, if they are on a planet that lacks a moon, the Attack Ball seems to compensate for this by making a holographic projection..." According to which anime? No citation. Is this one of the specifics of GT? I'm a bit confused on what you're saying about the concept since I'm asking if it is differentiated from plain moonlight. Seems that in the canon, they are never used mechanically, no distinction beyond moonlight and other celestial bodies don't work (Bardock)

Comment: note: i'm having a discussion with someone about whether saiyan biology is just reacting to the waves or there is anything supposedly special about those frequencies lol. this is good feedback but i am looking for ability to cite the origin of the concept of blutz waves as anything besides moonlight, whether in either series. had assumed that the origin of the name would be enough but not sure after reading this

Comment: The anime is reffering to the DBZ anime, it was mentioned in an episode during the battle with Raditz. In GT it was referrenced that the concept of the moon simulator is what allowed Bulma to product the Blutz Wave Cannon. In terms of the concept, I have editted my answer please check it out. Lastly, the energy is reffered to as moon light because nobody other than Bardock knew that moons aren't the only source of energy, planets and other large celestial entities can generate it as well. This is spoken about but never shown.

Comment: ah I see so it was capable of being used mechanically, but it's still a moon simulator rather than a blutz wave simulator until GT, which may be the same thing if canon. cool thx for clarifying that. well maybe vegeta will sprout a tail in the tournament of power and we will find out more haha.

Comment: I am hoping for something way more detailed. I am waiting for a new saiyan call her "Zill" for example. To fight with them and use the ssb transformation. Running neck and neck in a 2v1 with Goku and Vegeta she injects in her neck a sort of Blutz Wave extract becoming a Giant Azure Ape that has some crazy awesome name and can transcend space and time.

Comment: Like on a serious note the exploration of the blutz wave and the transformation is such a good plot point that is just flat out ignored.

Answer (score -1):

Vegeta mentioned blutz waves in episode 31 of DBZ and created them artificially to transform and fight Goku.